# Ambiguous table name exception, even with schema set

Tags: java, dbunit

I have a class that extends `JdbcBasedDBTestCase`, and I implemented all the required getters from the abstract class: `getDriverClass()`, `getPassword()`, `getUsername()`, `getConnectionUrl()`. My connection URL looks like this: `jdbc:mysql://database_location:port/database_name`.

I'm going with step 2: http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/howto.html

In the constructor I have the schema set as this:

`System.setProperty( PropertiesBasedJdbcDatabaseTester.DBUNIT_SCHEMA, "database_name" );`

I have the properties set in the constructor.

Yet when I run the tests I get the ambiguous table name exception:
`org.dbunit.database.AmbiguousTableNameException: users`

I enabled the setting `DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_QUALIFIED_TABLE_NAMES` to `true` as well and also disabled it and still get the error.

What is going on??

Comment: you enabled a feature and did not follow what it requires, the JavaDoc is very clear on what that feature does and how to use it. You are not using it correctly, you must provide a fully qualified tablename, you are clearly not doing that.

Comment: Well I also tried it with true and false set and I still get the error.

Comment: then provide a fully qualified tablename like the documentation says it requires.

Comment: I still get the same error, providing a fully qualified table name w/ the setting on OR not providing a fully qualified table name with the setting off.